# How can I keep vertex color accurate on a voxel model thats been converted to a lower poly model?

Tags: uv, workflow, texture-baking, vertex-colors

I'm importing voxel models into Blender from Qubicle, and then turning them into low poly models.  I'm using vertex paint, and want to keep each face one solid color.  After finishing my model and vertex paint, I create a lower poly model and try to bake the vertex paint to the low poly model, however the colors get all splotchy.  The other alternative I've seen is baking the vertex color data to a texture, but when I apply the material after UV unwrapping to the low poly model there are slight errors, creating seams, similar to mip mapping without padding.

Unwrapping the model manually would be a huge pain because it's made up of tons of tiny cubes and triangles.  It is however important to use the high poly model in order to keep the color per face image, even if that face no longer exists.  Basically pixel art textures on 3D models, but painted directly on the model.

Is there a way to avoid UV unwrapping considering that the vertex paint data is already there?  can I convert the vertex paint data to a material, or texture paint while keeping everything pixel perfect?  Qubicle UV unwraps perfectly while exporting lower poly models and keeps the texture color perfectly, which would be great if I didn't have to actually edit the model, however I do, so that isn't much help to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer it seems is to bake your vertex colors to a texture after smart unwrapping and then select your UVs in the viewer, hit shift + s and snap selected to pixels.  it locks exactly to where your vertexes were.  this is probably because I was using exact increments.  you can then convert your model to a lower poly model (i used limited dissolve) and your UVs will be the same as your high poly model, and you will keep your vertex paint (now converted to a texture) precise.